# Get error while opening Zoom

Tags: windows-10

I have a problem with the Zoom app. Every time I try to open this app it shows this error:

[image]

If I uninstall and reinstall this program it works fine, but if I quit once it won't open again and shows this error.

OS: Windows 10 Pro 64bit version 2004 (OS Build 19041.330)

Comment: Have you looked up that error code?

Comment: 0xc000003e is a data error.  Have you checked your drive for errors?

Comment: Also, know that there still many issues with v 2004.. clearly they haven't all been ironed out yet.

Comment: Here why the error came. Zoom setup is not completely installed all file in the Drive(I think Windows Defender Antivirus Blocked the installation)after i disabled Real time Protection and installed zoom in my another PC and copied and pasted all Zoom files in Windows 10 PC. Now all are working fine

Comment: Please submit that as an answer to your question and accept it.